# Why pip uses global packages when created a clean virtualenv using python2.7?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I tried different suggestions from other topic but no one helped. I have latest virtualenv and pip installed.

What I do thats:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip list
```

it shows me global packages.

Also tried `export PYTHONPATH=` before creating venv, but nothing helped. 
On my laptop it works but on remote server - does not.

Maybe there is any global settings/config for it??

UPDATED:
It is only for python2, for python3 works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that WebFaction hosting has python customisations which includes packages at ~/lib/python2.7 directory.

I asked the support and a guy created an empty file named sitecustomize.py in the /home/user/webapps/myapp/env/lib/python2.7

That empty file overrides python customizations and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

i would say to update the python version. i have 2.7.15 and runs as expected. Also try --no-site-packages to workaround. this should not give access to global site-packages